# How do I return a single entity with a self-join using LINQ (in VB.NET)?

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

I am trying to return a single entity class ("category") with a LINQ query (in VB.NET) with a JOIN, but it isn't working.  I think it's either because:

- I'm getting an IEnumerable resultset (of 1) OR
- I'm getting    more than just the first-table-in-the-join's
  columns back

because I get this invalid type cast exception:

```
    Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[category]' 
    to type 'category'.
```

Here is SQL that does what I want (note how I don't want any columns from the joined table):

```
      select subcat.*
      From category as cat
      join category as parentcat On cat.cat_id = cat.parent_cat_id
      Where parentcat.cat_url = 'dogs'
        And cat.cat_url = 'poodles'
```

Here's the LINQ code I have that works in LINQPad:

```
   dim q = From cat In categories _
        Join parentcat In categories On parentcat.cat_id Equals cat.parent_cat_id _
        Where parentcat.cat_url.ToLower = "dogs" _
              And cat.cat_url.ToLower = "poodles" _
            Select categories.SingleOrDefault(function(c) c.cat_id = cat.cat_id)
   q.dumb
```

But this doesn't work in my "CategoryRepository" function in VB.NET:

```
        Public Function GetCategoryByURL(ByVal strCatURL As String, ByVal strSubCatURL As String) As category Implements ICategoryRepository.GetCategoryByURL
        Return From cat In db.categories _
                Join parentcat In db.categories On parentcat.cat_id Equals cat.parent_cat_id _
            Where parentcat.cat_url.ToLower = strCatURL.ToLower _
              And cat.cat_url.ToLower = strSubCatURL.ToLower _
            Select db.categories.SingleOrDefault(Function(C) C.cat_id = cat.cat_id)
        End Function
```

How do I make it to return a single instance of the "category" class?  (I need it that way because I have this same function overloaded that returns a single instance ... and that works!) I have verified that the database is correct and it should return the "poodles" category.

I'm new to LINQ, so I'm sure there is something very obvious that I'm doing incorrectly, so I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query categories and you return the statement `db.categories.SingleOrDefault(Function(C) C.cat_id = cat.cat_id)` *for each* row in the result set. This is always an `IQueryable` even though it may have 0 or 1 results. You must do `SingleOrDefault()` over the whole query:

```
Dim query = From cat In db.categories _
            Join parentcat In db.categories On parentcat.cat_id
                                        Equals cat.parent_cat_id _
            Where parentcat.cat_url.ToLower = strCatURL.ToLower _
            And cat.cat_url.ToLower = strSubCatURL.ToLower _
            Select cat
Return query.SingleOrDefault()
```